# capture the elements in a text area box with a button, and put them into an array in memory

Tags: jquery, json

I'm attempting to write a huge array in the computer memory and then save the final output as .json, but i'm having trouble writing a script that will continually update an array on my page that will sit in the browsers memory until the user is ready to save their final .json file.

I have 3 form elements on my page that will do this. A combobox, textarea & button.

The user will hit the page, and select an option from the combobox. They will then put some numbers in the textarea field. they will then click a button, and those numbers will be stored in an array that is continually updated in memory.

i'm not too sure of the rules here, but i've started writing some code on jsfiddle that will do this: http://jsfiddle.net/PJ7s6/4/

From my understanding, I would want to loop through my original array, and use .val() or something of the sort to capture the id on the  node, then go into my array, and find the "section" associated with that ID, then write the text from the textarea into the "array: [] value in my response.

Has anyone done anything like this before?

I've only been at this jquery, json, looping stuff for about 6 months and i'm finally starting to get it. I appreciate everyone that has given me support during this trek!

Comment: not huge.. Here is an updated version on jsfiddle that is actaully building the dropdown dynamically.  http://jsfiddle.net/PJ7s6/7/

Comment: Actually, I'm lying. It can get quite huge. I have a browser requirement though - Chrome or FF. So, I'm not too concerned with how much memory this uses up.  I'll keep editing that fiddle. Feel free to branch if you care to take a wack at it.

Comment: Do you think you'll have, say, a thousand records in the array? More or less? Also, are you experiencing any issues with what you have right now?

Comment: Well I'm such a noob that i haven't figure out how to append to an array in memory yet :-/  So, i'm not too sure how this will perform anyway. And It can grow up to about 500 records. I haven't seen anything bigger than 500 records with what I'm doing. And, unfortunately, writing this to a DB is out of the question.

Comment: The basic method: `your_array.push( another_object );`

Answer (score 0):

From our conversation in the comments, it doesn't sound like you actually have an issue to worry about. Browser memory will be fine for the task at hand. It does sound like you need to learn a bit about javascript array and object manipulation.

The basic way to add to an array is `push`:

```
var your_array = []; // an empty array
your_array.push( 'red', 'orange', 'yellow' );
your_array.push( 'green', 'blue', 'purple' );
```

`your_array` would now include all 6 colors. It gets more complex than that, but that's the basic start.

From here, I'd ask more questions (read: new questions on SO) that are more specific to your current needs, and hopefully you'll get more help!

Comment: I got the push part down, but i'm not entirely sure about how to grab the items that are in the text area, and then push the data into the array based on the array index. I'll keep pounding away at it and see what sticks.

Comment: It's pretty much working now :  <a href="jsfiddle.net/PJ7s6/7">jsfiddle.net/PJ7s6/7</a>, however, it's not continually adding the items that i'm placing in memory.. it lets me do the first one, then chokes. I'll keep at it..